# Compiler variance for ambiguous copy-assignment from empty-braces

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

I've been trying to understand the rationale for `std::nullopt_t` to not be allowed to be `DefaultConstructible` in C++17 (where it was introduced) and beyond, and stepped over some compiler variance confusion in the process.

Consider the following spec-violating (it is `DefaultConstructible`) implementation of `nullopt_t`:

```
struct nullopt_t {
    explicit constexpr nullopt_t() = default;
};
```

which is an aggregate in C++11 and C++14 (no user-*provided* ctors), but which is not an aggregate in C++17 (`explicit` ctor) and C++20 (user-*declared* ctor).

Now consider the following example:

```
struct S {
    constexpr S() {}
    S(S const&) {}
    S& operator=(S const&) { return *this; }   // #1
    S& operator=(nullopt_t) { return *this; }  // #2
};

int main() {
    S s{};
    s = {};  // GCC error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (#1 and #2)
}
```

This is rejected by GCC (various versions, say v11.0) throughout C++11 to C++20, but is accepted by both Clang (say v12.0) and MSVC (v19.28) throughout C++11 to C++20.

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/Tf96s4Krf)

My initial assumptions were that the program:

- is ill-formed in C++11 and C++14, as `nullopt_t` (as above) is an aggregate, whereas it
- is well-formed in C++17 and C++20, as it is no longer an aggregate, meaning that its *explicit* default constructor should prohibit copy-list-init of a temporary `nullopt_t` object as needed for the copy assignment operator at `#2` to be viable,

but none of the compilers agree in full with this theory, some I'm probably missing something.

What compiler is correct here (if any), and how do we explain it by relevant standard sections (and DR:s, if relevant)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why is `nullopt_t` required to be `DefaultConstructible` in the first place?

The spec requirement that `nullopt_t` shall not be `DefaultConstructible` is arguably, in retrospect, a mistake based on some LWG and CWG confusion around tag types, and the resolution of this confusion which came only *after* `std::optional` was [brought in from the Library Fundamentals TS Components](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0220r1.html).

First of all, the current (C++17, C++20) spec of `nullopt_t`, [[optional.nullopt]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/optional.nullopt#2), requires [**emphasis** mine]:

> Type `nullopt_­t` **shall not have a default constructor** or an initializer-list constructor, and shall not be an aggregate.

and its main use is described in the previous section, [[optional.nullopt]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/optional.nullopt#1):

> [...] In particular, `optional<T>` has a constructor with `nullopt_­t` as a single argument; this indicates that an optional object not containing a value shall be constructed.

Now, [P0032R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0032r3.pdf) (*Homogeneous interface for `variant`, `any` and `optional`*), one of the papers which was part of introducing `std::optional`, has a discussion around `nullopt_t`, tag types in general, and the `DefaultConstructible` requirement [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### No default constructible
>
> While adapting `optional<T>` to the new `in_place_t` type we found
> that we cannot anymore use `in_place_t{}`. The authors don't consider
> this a big limitation as the user can use `in_place` instead. It needs
> to be noted that this is in line with the behavior of `nullopt_t` as
> `nullopt_t{}` fails as no default constructible. However `nullptr_t{}`
> seems to be well formed.
>
> #### Not assignable from `{}`
>
> After a deeper analysis we found also that the old `in_place_t`
> supported `in_place_t t = {};`. The authors don't consider this a big limitation as we don't expect that a lot of users could use this and the user can use
> `in_place` instead.
>
> ```
> in_place_t t;
> t = in_place;
> ```
>
> It needs to be noted that this is in line with the behavior of
> `nullopt_t` as the following compile fails.
>
> ```
> nullopt_t t = {}; // compile fails
> ```
>
> However `nullptr_t` seems to be support it.
>
> ```
> nullptr_t t = {}; // compile pass
> ```
>
> **To re-enforce this design, there is an pending issue 2510-Tag types should not be `DefaultConstructible`** Core issue 2510.

And indeed, the *initial* proposed resolution of [LWG Core Issue 2510](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2510) *was* to require all tag types to not be `DefaultConstructible` [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### (LWG) 2510. Tag types should not be `DefaultConstructible`
>
> [...]
>
> **Previous resolution [SUPERSEDED]:**
>
> [...] Add a new paragraph after 20.2 [utility]/2 (following the header  synopsis):
>
> - -?- Type `piecewise_construct_t` **shall not have a default constructor.** It shall be a literal type. Constant `piecewise_construct` shall be initialized with an argument of literal type.

This resolution was superseded, however, as there were overlap with [CWG Core Issue 1518](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1518), which was eventually resolved in a way that did not require tag types to not be `DefaultConstructible`, as `explicit` would suffice [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### (CWG) 1518. Explicit default constructors and copy-list-initialization
>
> [...]
>
> **Additional note, October, 2015:**
>
> It has been suggested that the resolution of issue 1630 **went too far in allowing use of explicit constructors for default initialization**, and that default initialization should be considered to model copy initialization instead. The resolution of this issue would provide an opportunity to adjust that.
>
> **Proposed resolution (October, 2015):**
>
> Change 12.2.2.4 [over.match.ctor] paragraph 1 as follows:
>
> [...] For direct-initialization <s>**or default-initialization**</s>, the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized. [...]

as long as `explicit` also implied that the type was not an aggregate, which in turn was the final resolution of LWG Core Issue 2510 (based on the final resolution of CWG Core Issue 1518)

> #### (LWG) 2510. Tag types should not be `DefaultConstructible`
>
> [...]
>
> **Proposed resolution:**
>
> [...] In 20.2 [utility]/2, change the header  synopsis:
>
> - ```
>   // 20.3.5, pair piecewise construction
>   struct piecewise_construct_t { explicit piecewise_construct_t() = default; };
>   constexpr piecewise_construct_t piecewise_construct{};
>   ```
>
> [...]

These latter changes, however, were not brought into the proposal for `std::optional`, arguably an oversight, and I would like to claim that `nullopt_t` need not be required to not be `DefaultConstructible`, only, like other tag types, that it should have a user-declared `explicit` constructor, which bans it from a candidate for empty-braces copy-list-init both by it not being an aggregate and by the only candidate constructor being `explicit`.

#### Which compiler is right and wrong here?

Given the LWG 2510, CWG 1518 (and other) confusion, let's focus on C++17 and beyond. In this case, GCC is arguably wrong to reject the program, whereas Clang and MSVC are correct to accept it.

Why?

Because the `S& operator=(nullopt_t)` assignment operator is not viable for the assignment `s = {};`, as the empty braces `{}` would require either aggregate initialization or copy-list-initialization to create a `nullopt_t` (temporary) object. `nullopt_t`, however (by the idiomatic tag implementation: my implementation above), as per as per [P0398R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0398r0.html) (which resolves CWG Core Issue 1518), is neither an aggregate nor does its default constructor participate in copy-list-initialization (from empty braces).

This likely falls under the following GCC bug report:

- [Bug 54835 - (C++11)(DR 1518) Explicit default constructors not respected during copy-list-initialization](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54835)

which was listed as `SUSPENDED` in 2015-06-15, before the change in the resolution of CWG Core Issue 1630 (*"resolution of issue 1630 went too far"*). The ticket is now re-opened based on a ping from this Q&A.